# Binding a ListView to an ObservableSet

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, observable

I would like to know if there is a way to bind an `ObservableSet` to a `ListView`  or an `ObservableList` bidirectional to an `ObservableSet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's not completely possible to do this, since lists and sets have different functionality (sets are unordered while lists are ordered; lists can contain duplicates but sets cannot).

You can ensure a `ListView` displays the elements from an `ObservableSet` with code similar to the following:

```
ObservableSet<String> set = FXCollections.observableSet();
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
set.addListener((Change<? extends String> c) -> {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
        listView.getItems().add(c.getElementAdded());
    }
    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
        listView.getItems().remove(c.getElementRemoved());
    }
});
```

If the `ListView` might be manipulated independently of the set, then you can register a (somewhat) similar listener with `listView.getItems()`, and update the set accordingly.